# extract the column values that bigger than all the values of other column | python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` that has multiple values:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file1.tsv', names=['c1'], header=None, skiprows=0, sep='\t')

c1
0.94774
0.8367
0.21637
0.8474
0.384784
```

And another dataframe `dn` that also have multiple values:

```
dn = pd.read_csv('file2.tsv', names=['c1'], header=None, skiprows=0, sep='\t')

c1
0.33363
0.233
0.45454
0.243
0.28272
0.4874
0.4547
0.1822
```

I want return a dataframe that has all the values of `df` that's bigger than all the values of `dn`

So, the output will be:

> c1 
>   0.94774 
>   0.8367 
>   0.8474

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is bigger than all, it is bigger than the maximum value:

```
df[df['c1'] > dn['c1'].max()]
#        c1
#0  0.94774
#1  0.83670
#3  0.84740
```